# Deegree Configuration of existing tile cache (.png files) as datasource for wms and wmts

Tags: wms, wmts, tilecache, deegree

I am unsuccessful in configuring an existing png-file tile cache that I want to use as data source for the provision of wms and wmts services.

Despite having worked myself through the deegree documentation and the utah example data set (that uses a geotiff-tile cache) I did apparently not configure deegree correctly.

I have a tile cache having the structure zz/xx/yy.png
with a total amount of 9 zoom levels.

Within the datasource/tile/tilematrixset directory I have defined this tile cache as follows (example for two zoom levels):

```
<TileMatrixSet xmlns="http://www.deegree.org/datasource/tile/tilematrixset" configVersion="3.2.0">

  <CRS>urn:ogc:def:crs:EPSG::31467</CRS>

  <TileMatrix>
    <Identifier>0</Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>1111111</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>427461.787361 103142.057325</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>1024</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>1024</MatrixHeight>
  </TileMatrix>
  <TileMatrix>
    <Identifier>01</Identifier>
    <ScaleDenominator>555555</ScaleDenominator>
    <TopLeftCorner>427461.787361 103142.057325</TopLeftCorner>
    <TileWidth>256</TileWidth>
    <TileHeight>256</TileHeight>
    <MatrixWidth>512</MatrixWidth>
    <MatrixHeight>512</MatrixHeight>
  </TileMatrix>
</TileMatrixSet>
```

I do not know how to set up the required xml document in the xml document within the datasource/tile/ directory since I do not know if my cache qualifies as a filesystem cache.

Answer (score 1):

This questions has been unanswered for quite a while but someone may find it useful to know that the recent version of the deegree webservices handbook has a step-by-step description how to setup a WMTS based on a GeoTIFF. Have a look on https://download.deegree.org/documentation/current/html/#_a_complete_wmts_configuration_example_based_on_a_geotifftilestore how the TileMatrixSet is defined.

When using tile cache the steps are quite similar:

1. get and install tile cache as documented in http://tilecache.org/
2. use the `tilecache.cfg` as a starting point and apply the changes for the source WMS, number of layers and file type as needed
3. build the tile cache with the `tilecache_seed.py` script and move the generated files to the deegree workspace such as `./data/basemap/`
4. now create the deegree TileMatrixSet config file matching the tile cache configuration (as you did)
5. continue with the steps described in the deegree webservices handbook in chapter 5.3.4. as linked above.

For step 3 use a FileSystemTileStore instead of the GeoTIFFTileStore as shown in the following example:

```
<FileSystemTileStore xmlns="http://www.deegree.org/datasource/tile/filesystem" xmlns:md="http://www.deegree.org/metadata/spatial" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.deegree.org/datasource/tile/filesystem http://schemas.deegree.org/datasource/tile/filesystem/3.4.0/filesystem.xsd" configVersion="3.4.0">

  <TileDataSet>
    <Identifier>basemap</Identifier>
    <TileMatrixSetId>basemapTileMatrixSet</TileMatrixSetId> <!-- the name of the file in datasource/tile/tilematrixset -->
    <TileCacheDiskLayout>
      <LayerDirectory>../../data/basemap</LayerDirectory>
      <FileType>png</FileType>
    </TileCacheDiskLayout>
  </TileDataSet>

</FileSystemTileStore>
```